# How to load and modify .cer file into memory

Tags: java, x509certificate

The following code loads test.cer file (Which is X509 Certificate) into memory. Is that possible to modify its fields when it is now in the memory, right? It is easy to output any field for example `load.getPublicKey()` but I want to change the first byte from the public key and output it again after changing. How would I do that?

```
File f= new File("Users/Desktop/JavaFolder/test.cer");    
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
while (in.available() > 0) {
    Certificate load = cf.generateCertificate(in); 
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Given what a certificate is, this seems to be a strange requirement, can you explain your use case?

Comment: The main use case is to know how to modify the certificate contents itself after uploading it into the memory that why I came up with public key example. I want to know this because I'm required to show something similar to that for signature verification where any change in the certificate makes it unsound for verification

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917034/modifying-x509-certificate

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21917034/207421. One thread per question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have the `Certificate`:

```
Certificate cert = ....
PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
byte[] originalPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
byte[] modifiedPublicKey = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(originalPublicKey , originalPublicKey .length);// make a copy
modifiedPublicKey[0] = !modifiedPublicKey[0]; // modify something
print(originalPublicKey); // your "print" method - implement it how you like it e.g., Arrays.toString(originalPublicKey)
print(modifiedPublicKey ); // your "print" method - implement it how you like it e.g., Arrays.toString(modifiedPublicKey)
```

See the javadoc reference

- [java.security.PublicKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html)
- [java.security.cert.Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html)
- [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)